# drawn circle is not the same size as a drawn bitmap

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-bitmap

I have been trying to code collision for a school project, however I quickly noticed that when I draw a bitmap using the `canvas.DrawBitmap(currentImage, position.X, position.Y, paint)` function, it did not match the size of the radius, as the image appeared bigger then the actual circle. this is not an issue when i use the `canvas.DrawCircle(position.X, position.Y, size.Width / 2, new Paint() { Color = Color.Black })` function, as it is scaled properly. How do I create a bitmap that is scaled correctly to the actual circle?

- relevent code:

  ```
    public Sprite(float x, float y, float size, Context context) : base(x, y)
    {
        int id = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(General.IMG_BALL).GetValue(null);
        image = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, id);
        this.size = new SizeF(size, size);
        paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        paint.AntiAlias = false;
        paint.FilterBitmap = false;
        paint.Dither = true;
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
    }

    public void DisplayImage(Canvas c)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.PostTranslate(position.X, position.Y);
        matrix.PreScale(size.Width, size.Height);
        c.DrawBitmap(image, matrix, paint);
    }
  ```
- results using `canvas.DrawCircle(position.X, position.Y, size.Width / 2, new Paint() { Color = Color.Black })`  (correct scaling, no bitmap, radius = 100):
  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tppxP.png)
- results using the DrawImage(canvas) function I made (wrong scaling, using bitmap, radius = 1 so it can fit in the image)
  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khDTR.png)

Comment: Where is the code for drawing the circle?  What are the actual dimensions of the bitmap?

Comment: @Jason the code I used to draw a circle originally was `c.DrawCircle(position.X, position.Y, size.Width / 2, new Paint() { Color = Color.Black })` but for drawing a circle using a bitmap I use the DisplayImage function I made. the original image is 318px by 318px. I did not scale the actual bitmap but used `matrix.PreScale(size.Width, size.Height)` to scale it in the canvas. I don't know how to scale the bitmap properly. I have attached images to the original post

Comment: The parameters x and y in `DrawCircle` represent [the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate of the center of the circle to be drawn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.canvas.drawcircle?view=net-android-34.0), while in `DrawBitmap`, the parameters x and y represent [the X coordinate and Y coordinate for where to draw the bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.canvas.drawbitmap?view=net-android-34.0).